# How can I show git log of any additons/deletions to a subdirectory one level but not recursive?

Tags: git

I'd like to know a git log of commits that added or removed a subdirectory given a directory, and not include commits that modified things below the subdirectory

for example:

```
root
  dir-of-interest
     sub-a
         sub-a-1
            sub-a-2-other
         sub-a-2
            sub-a-2-other
     sub-b
         sub-b-1
         sub-b-2
            sub-b-2-other
     sub-c
     sub-d
     sub-f
     file1
```

where I can get the git commits directory additions/deletions to dir-of-interest and only that folder not any sub-sub directories.

results for `git log -?? dir-of-interest` would show the commits like these:

```
add of sub-a
add of sub-b
add of sub-d
delete of sub-e
add of sub-c
add of sub-f
add of file1
```

it would not include add-sub-a-2 and other level4/5/etc directories as that was a commit not directly updating the dir-of-interest folder

Comment: To clarify, git only tracks changes to files. It doesn't track additions/deletions of directories. So your question only makes sense if you are asking about viewing a log for when files in the subdirectory were added/deleted.

Comment: I see ok if I could see when a package.json file at top level was added would there be a command that provided that?

Comment: `git log -- <file name>` will give you the log for a single file.

Comment: will that support wild cards i.e. dir-of-interest/*/package.json?

Comment: Yes, since the shell will take care of the wild cards before passing execution to `git`.

Comment: `git` can process wildcards itself: `git log -- 'dir-of-interest/*/package.json'` (apostrophes used to protect `*` from the shell) works. Also `git log -- dir-of-interest/\*/package.json` (backslash for screening). Useful to work with files that are in the commit history but not in the working tree.